# Leer arhivos binarios en C (fread Matlab)

Tags: c, archivo, matlab, conversión-de-tipos, float

En Matlab tengo un archivo binario leído de esta forma:

```
fid = fopen('nombrearcihvo', 'r', 'ieee-le')
```

el contenido son flotantes cortos, o de 32 bits (4 bytes) y para leer el primer elemento uso lo siguiente:

```
fread(fid, 1, 'float32')
```

Y me arroja 0.6721

Pero necesito leerlo en un çodigo en C, y he utilizado el siguiente código

```
float v;
ifile = fopen(namefileI,"r");
fread((void*)(&v), sizeof(v), 1, ifile);
```

Para ver el resultado lo hago enviando el contenido de v a otro archivo
de la forma:

```
fwrite ((void*)(&v), sizeof(v), 1, fp);
```

Y me arroja estos símbolos:
±
,?

En realidad, he probado varias maneras, con ninguna que me haya dejado algo satisfecha ya que el resultado no parece coincidir con el que me arroja Matlab.

Mi pc es Little-Endian, por lo que debería estar leyendo igual, y el tipo float32 es el mismo de 4 bytes de C....

Qué código o pasos debería realizar para convertir los datos del archivo y obtener el mismo resultado que en Matlab ?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La forma en como estás utilizando las funciones es correcta. Es decir, el tipo de los argumentos como los tamaños son acorde a lo que necesitas. El problema no es está en el uso de `fopen()`, `fread()` o `fwrite()`.

Algo que hay que tener claro es que a la función `fwrite` no sabrá el tipo de los datos a los que se le hace apuntar. Esa es la intención de tener un `void *` como argumento. La función espera una dirección inicial y un tamaño para hacer una escritura en crudo (byte por byte) elemento por elemento.

Por tu descripción esperas que fwrite haga la conversión de punto flotante a caracteres para ser leídos porteriormente en un archivo de texto. Eso no ocurrirá con 'fwrite()'. Es por eso que en su lugar, al abrir dicho archivo sólamente ves caracteres inesperados:

> ± ,?

Al abrir dicho archivo se desplegarán en pantalla en base al caracter UTF-8 correspondiente:

- ? en UTF-8 (hex) es 0x3F
- , en UTF-8 (hex) es 0x2C
- ' ' (espacio) en UTF-8 (hex) es 0x20
- ± en UTF-8 (hex) es 0xC2B1

Asumiendo que ese es el órden en cómo te aparecen los caracteres, ahora, si concatenamos todos estos datos nos da lo siguiente:

```
0x3F2C20C2B1
```

Si tomamos los 32 bits mas significativos:

```
0x3F2C20C2
```

y si [decoficamos](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) el valor en base al estándar IEEE-754 obtendremos:

```
0.67237484
```

El cual no es exactamente 0.6721 pero está en el rango. Si usamos la misma herramienta para obtener la representación hexadecimal de 0.6721 obtenemos:

```
0x3f2c0ebf
```

Podemos notar aquí que los dos primeros caracteres corresponden. Algo que considerar, y en base al comentario hecho por @eferion es que la precisión del tipo de datos `float`es de 6 dígitos. El error que vemos aquí pudiera ser por un error de conversión en las cifras mostradas.

Comment: El problema que comentas de los decimales tiene que ver con la precisión... `float` tiene una precisión de 6 dígitos (el resto son considerados basura o no fiables) en el caso de `double` creo recordar que son justamente el doble, 12. Quizás deberías incluir eso en tu respuesta

Comment: Si, ahora lo imprimí de la forma 
printf("valor = 0x%x (decimal:%2.4f)\n",v, v); Y puedo ver el valor con los 4 decimales (ya que necesito valores en short float), ahora bien, el float lo tengo que almacenar por lo que mi requisito estaría funcionando ..... Pero me quedó la duda de como almacenar el valor decimal en un archivo. Quizás con fprintf tenga más suerte, luego les cuento!

Comment: Buen comentario @eferion. Lo agregaré a la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto Romina.